# Integral of product of exponential function and polynomial function

Tags: integration, polynomials, definite-integrals, exponential-function

Is there a closed form solution to this integral?
$$\int_{a}^{b}x^ne^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$$
where, $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $n$ is a non negative integer.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is incomplete Gamma function a good thing?: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+x%5En+exp%28-x%5E2%2F2%29

Comment: Similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2337846/399263

Answer (score 1):

This integral involves incomplete Gamma functions. You can use either upper or lower incomplete variants. I'll choose lower:
$$\int_{a}^{b}x^ne^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx = 2^{n/2}\int_{a^2/2}^{b^2/2} u^{(n+1)/2}e^{-u}du\\ = 2^{n/2}\Big[ \int_{0}^{b^2/2} u^{(n+1)/2}e^{-u}du - \int_{0}^{a^2/2} u^{(n+1)/2}e^{-u}du\Big]\\
= 2^{n/2}\Big[\gamma\Big(\frac{n+3}{2}, \frac{b^2}{2}\Big) - \gamma\Big(\frac{n+3}{2}, \frac{a^2}{2}\Big)\Big].$$

Some background: The Gamma function is defined as
$$ \Gamma(s+1) = \int_0^\infty x^s e^{-x} dx. $$
This generalizes the factorial function to non-integer values. For example, one can show that $\Gamma(s+1)=s!$ for integer $s$, and that the Gamma function satisfies the recursion $\Gamma(s+1) = s \Gamma(s)$, analogous to $n!=n(n-1)!$ satisfied by the factorial. When the integration limit of a Gamma function is "*not correct*", we have an incomplete Gamma function:
$$ \gamma(s+1,a) = \int_0^a x^s e^{-x} dx. $$
This is what shows up in your integral. For curiosity, the "incomplete" recursion relation is $\gamma(s+1,x) = s \gamma(s,x) - x^s e^{-x}. $